# Windows Authentication Pop up Issue in Selinum Automation

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, automation, ui-automation

I am trying to write UI Automation for a Portal but while Authentication Chrome after entering User name a Pop up comes which can not be handled by selenium c#

I have tried using
https://username:password{siteurl}.com

But it didn't work. Also Auto IT nuget is not working. Any suggestions will be really helpful

PFB the screenshot for the same.

[image: Issu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't try using a "robot" keyboard which just types in the keyboard. There is no need for the element to be inside the HTML page, as long as you know the prompt is focused:

Install the NuGet InputSimulator:

```
InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();  
sim.Keyboard.TextEntry("User123"); 
sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.TAB); 
sim.Keyboard.TextEntry("Password123"); 
sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
```

This way you just "hit" the keyboard. You code works regardless of the webpage.

Comment: This works but when we run the test cases in pipeline we get this error:

```System.Exception: Some simulated input commands were not sent successfully. The most common reason for this happening are the security features of Windows including User Interface Privacy Isolation (UIPI). Your application can only send commands to applications of the same or lower elevation. Similarly certain commands are restricted to Accessibility/UIAutomation applications. Refer to the project home page and the code samples for more information.```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue when I run windows automation test cases using azure devops pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If the popping prompt is not part of the HTML page, but a Windows alert, you can try using the keyboard:

```
new Actions(driver).SendKeys("User_Name").Perform();
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(Keys.Tab).Perform();
new Actions(driver).SendKeys("Password_here").Perform();
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(Keys.Tab).Perform();
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Perform();
```

Basically you just type the user_name and password and hit the Enter key using Selenium.

Comment: This is not working. It's working only on HTML page.

Comment: @SahilBansal Enter the website, right click on the password input element and click inspect. Please attach a screenshot

Comment: element can not be inspected, That's not HTML, Its Windows Authentication Pop up. You can try this on below URL:
https://ms.portal.azure.com/
Try in incognito mode

Answer (score -1):

I am too facing the same issue. I have used AutoIT to login into Windows Authentication (code below). This code works fine if we run the scripts from any platform like Visual Studio but when I trigger release pipeline, the code is unable to identity the active chromedriver session. It seems that the Chromedriver is not in focus when we execute from release pipeline.

I have tried to bring the chromedriver in focus like AddAdditionalCapability("requireWindowFocus", true) or action.MoveByOffset(0, 0).Click().Build().Perform() for the windows authentication to work

Please suggest a solution for this.

```
                    AutoItX.WinWaitActive("Sign in", "", 10);
                    AutoItX.WinActivate("Sign in");
                    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(username);
                    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(password);
                    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

-AJ

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34286515)